# Create a checkpoint in a foreach statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code that put an X in a cell depending on a offset cell value, for exemple if the offset cell has a value of 3, it will put an X in the cell and decrement the offset cell value, i want to save the location of that cell and start the next for each with it.

```
 For Each Cell In plage    
 If (Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> 0) Then


    If (Cell.Value <> "X") Then


    Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value - 1

    Cell.Value = "X"
    Checkpoint = Cell.Address
    Exit For

    Else

    Cell.Value = ""

    GoTo NextStep

    End If

    Exit For

Else

    Cell.Value = ""

 End If

 NextStep:

 Next Cell
```

The problem i am having with the current code is it start the loop all over again while i want it to keep till the end of the lines, until all offset value are equal to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below (there are notes on the code). If you face difficulties let me know.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    'In this example we assume that the data you want to loop appear in Column A

    Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long
    Dim Checkpoint As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- Change sheet name if needed

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '< -Fins the lastrow of the column you want to loop

        For i = 2 To Lastrow ' < -Start looping from row 2 to Lastrow fo the column

             If .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value <> 0 Then '<- You are looping

                If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "X" Then

                    .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value = .Range("A" & i).Offset(0, 1).Value - 1

                    .Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value & "X"
                    Checkpoint = .Range("A" & i).Address

                Else

                    .Range("A" & i).Value = ""

                End If

            Else

                .Range("A" & i).Value = ""

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you code, i tried it and it worked, the problem is i want it to add one X each time i press the button

Comment: I have edited the answer. Could you please try again?

Comment: I tried your eddited code, its better but it still put an X if he find a 0 in the offset cell, also i don't see the point of the checkpoint variable

Answer (score 0):

Is `plage` a range?

If so, you could update it to start from the `checkpoint` and include all cells up to some `lastCell` for example.

Something like:

```
set plage=thisWorkbook.Worksheets("Your Worksheet").Range(checkpoint,lastCell)
```

That way the next `For-Each` should start from your `checkpoint`.

BTW if I understand correctly what you'e trying to do, I would suggest you replace `cell.value=""` with `cell.clearContents`